# Showing $f(x)\le 2$ for all $x\in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Let $F:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be continous such that for all $x\in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ we have $f(x)\le 2$. Show that for all $x\in [0,1]$ we have $f(x)\le 2$.

I'm going to write the answer I got (it isn't mine):

Let's assume by contraposition that there exists $x\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)\gt 2$, then it has to be irrational. This x will be denoted by $f(x)=2+a$ where $a\gt 0$.

Now take a rational sequence $x_n$ that is converging to $x$ such that $x_n\in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

From continuity $f(x_n)\to2+a=f(x)$ therefore, for $\epsilon=\frac a 2 , \exists\delta\gt0$ such that, $0\lt |x_n-x|\lt \delta\Rightarrow |f(x_n)-f(x)|\lt \frac a 2$

But for each $j, x_j\in \mathbb Q$, $f(x_j)\le 2$ in contradiction that there are elements that satisfy $2+\frac a 2 \lt f(x_n)$. $\square$

Is it correct ? Is there another way to prove it ?

Why did he use the defintion for uniform continuity ?

Why $\epsilon=\frac a 2$ ?

Note: we can't use integration.

Comment: Yes, it is correct!

Comment: It is true for all $\epsilon$ , thus he can use one which suits his purpose. Note, if it is chosen very big say $5a$ then that argument can't be used. $f(x) = 2 + a$. Thus if $\epsilon$ is chosen as $a/2$ all values in the interval $(f(x) - a/2 , f(x) + a/2)$ are still greater than 2. This he uses to get the contradiction. I don't think he has used definition of uniform continuity. It is the general form of continuity only. Just that he has used the sequences converging fact of continuity along with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An intuitively easy proof:

Let $g(x)=f(x)-2$. Suppose $g(k)>0$ for some irrational $k$, as $f$ is continuous $g$ too is continuous. By using sign preserving property of continuous function there exist some neighborhood of $k$ for which $g$ preserves sign(here positive). As $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense over $\mathbb{R}$(which means every neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}$ will contain rationals) there are rationals in the neighborhood, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Assume not;

There exist an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)>2$.By continiouty of $f$ at $x_0$,there exist a $\delta$ such that $f(x)>2$ for all $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$.But every open interval contain rational numbers thus,we have contradiction.